Share variables between build.gradle.kts and the application
Is it possible to share variables between build.gradle.kts and the main application? I would like to specify the application's name and version and few other settings only once.

There is a way using build sources. You can reference this code in your build.gradle.kts and your application, so you can define your variables there. Organizing Gradle Projects - Use buildSrc to abstract imperative logic
Example:
Project structure:
root/
├── build.gradle.kts
├── buildSrc/
│   └── src/
│       └── main/
│           └── kotlin/
│               └── Versions.kt
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── kotlin/
            └── com/
                └── example/
                    └── MyAppApplication.kt

Code:
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt
object Versions {
    const val appName = "MyAwesomeApp"
    const val appVersion = "1.0.0"
}

// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = Versions.appVersion // Using the version variable

application {
    applicationName = Versions.appName // Using the appname
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation(files("./buildSrc/build/libs/buildSrc.jar")) // Add the buildSrc.jar as dependency to use it in your main code. 
}

// src/main/kotlin/com/example/MyAppApplication.kt
package com.example.myapp

import Versions

@SpringBootApplication
class MyAppApplication {
    init {
        println("App Name: ${Versions.appName}, Version: ${Versions.appVersion}")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyAppApplication>(*args)
}

Hope this helps.

I spent the last four hours trying to replicate that setup, but unfortunatelly without luck. buildSrc seems to be visible only to build scripts. This means I couldn't figure out a way to make Versions visible for the main code. Strangely IntelliJ's autocomplete works in the main code but the task compileKotlin fails and says it was not able to find the class. I guess you have actually built a proof-of-concept to try out whether it would work, right? Would it be possible that you share it on GitHub?

I ended up generating a simple object class with gradle that I populate with these values and then use in my main application. This works's smoothly. I'm not entirely happy about it as it's just text, but it does the trick for now, until a better option emerges.

You are absolutely right. There was a crucial part missing. I've added it via edit. It's not the best solution but should be better than sharing text files.
